# excluding header, footer and watermark from last page with openxml

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I'm using `Open XML` (`DocumentFormat.OpenXml` nuget package) to generating a docx file. Here is my approach:

I have a file, named `template.docx`. In this file I have a `Cover Page` and a blank page which has `header`, `footer`, and a background image. Anyway, I first open the document, then append some text to the document, then close it.

In the other hand, I have a file named `template-back.docx` which I want to append that at the end of modified document (`template.docx`) above.

I'm able to do that, by using this snippet:

```
    public static void MergeDocumentWithPagebreak(string sourceFile, string destinationFile, string altChunkID) {
        using (var myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFile, true)) {

            var mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

            //Append page break
            var para = new Paragraph(new Run((new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
            mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(para, mainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);

            //Append file
            var chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
            AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkID);
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(destinationFile, FileMode.Open))
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
            var altChunk = new AltChunk{
                Id = altChunkID
            };
            mainPart.Document
                    .Body
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }
```

But, when I do that, the `header`, `footer`, and background image, are applied to the last page. I want to be able to exclude last page from getting those designs. I want it to be clean, simple and white. But googling the issue, had nothing to help. Do you have any idea please? Thanks in advance.

P.S.

> The original article about merging documents [here](https://yanziyang.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/openxml-add-page-break-and-merge-documents/):

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @G.Mich I asked this more than 5 years ago. Actually I cant remember at all. Sorry 

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky, but not so complicated.

First you have to understand how word works:

- By default, a word document is one section, and this one section share header and footer. If you want differents header / footer, you have to create a break at the end of a page to indicate "the next page is a new section".
- Once a new section is create, you must indicate "the new section don't share the same header / footer"

Some documentation on "how to create different header in word". http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/accommodate-different-headers-and-footers-in-a-word-document/

If we translate to your code, before inserting your document at the end of the other, you have to:

- Create a section break
- Inserting a new Header / footer in this section (an empty one)
- Insert your new document in the new section

To create the new header, some other documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc546917.aspx

**Trick:** if the document you insert don't contain header / footer, create empty ones and recopy them

**Information:** I tried to delete the `<w:headerReference r:id="rIdX" w:type="default"/>` or to set the r:id to 0 but it don't work. Create an empty header is the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Page break with the following code

```
Paragraph PageBreakParagraph = new Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page }));
```

I also saw that you are inserting after the last child which is not essential same as Appending but works well for you! Use this instead.

```
wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(PageBreakParagraph)
```

You need to add the section break to the section properties. You then need to append the section properties to the paragraph properties. Followed by appending the paragraph properties to a paragraph.

```
        Paragraph paragraph232 = new Paragraph();

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties220 = new ParagraphProperties();

        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties();
        SectionType sectionType1 = new SectionType(){ Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage };

        sectionProperties1.Append(sectionType1);

        paragraphProperties220.Append(sectionProperties1);

        paragraph232.Append(paragraphProperties220);

//Replace your last but one line with this one.

mainPart.Document
                .Body
                .Append(altChunk);
```

The resulting Open XML is:

```js
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:sectPr>
        <w:type w:val="nextPage" />
      </w:sectPr>
    </w:pPr>
  </w:p>
```

The Easiest way to do it is to actually create the document in word and then open in it in the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425), you can reflect the code and see what C# code would generate the various Open XML elements you are trying to achieve. Hope this helps!